# How to calibrate PT100 with Arduino

Tags: arduino, pt100

Im trying to use my PT100 with an Arduino-based PLC from Industrial Shields, which is basically an Arduino Mega encased in a plastic container.  Im using a 250Ω resistor, actually 237Ω resistor between Analog and Ground.
The pt100 range is -200 to 600C & the transmitter according to NFC scanner is -200 to 600C as well.

Here is my code:

```
int sensorValue = 0;
int temperature = 0;
int ReceivedByte = 0;
float f1 = 0;
float t1 = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("hi...");
  //analogReference(INTERNAL2V56);
}

void loop() {
  delay(1000);
  sensorValue = analogRead(A2);
  Serial.println(sensorValue);
  /**
   current voltage(250 Ohm) ADC Temperature
 -----------------------------------------------------
 4 mA 1 V 205 -50 C
 20 mA 5 V 1023 +150 C
   * 
   */
  //original 5V adc values from weber 194,971
  //SO-weber new values 10 bit ADC 97,485
  //204-1023 for 10V ADC with 2x237Ω
  // map the signals (using 194-971 for 5V and 97-485 for 10V)
  // to get decimal values, because map() doesn't work with floats)
  // V = 0.004A x 237Ω = 0.948V => 1024 x (0.948/5) = 194.5 lower bound
  // V = 0.020A x 237Ω = 4.74V => 1024 x (4.74/5) = 970.7 upper bound
  temperature=map(sensorValue,194,971,-200,600);
  f1 = temperature; // Float conversion
  Serial.print(f1);
  Serial.print("\n");
}
```

I was also told to try 500Ω (237x2=474Ω) with the full values of 10V (due to the datasheets from IS) instead of 5V but that doesn't pan out either as can seen in the results table below.  I tried:

A- 5V full value & 237Ω
B- 10V full value& 237Ω
C- 10V full value& 474Ω

I've tried all the wiring options available with my 3 wire pt100.

So Im wondering about 2 possibilities:
1. Which is the correct wiring configuration, because I want to eliminate that variable.

2. Could it be Industrial Shields datasheets are incorrect? I just checked the actual plc box and it reads "Analog 0-10VDC" so I dont think IS datasheet is incorrect.

UPDATING RESULTS:
What I dont like about room temp measurements is that its obviously off because it is no 10C in my office, its 22C with a thermometer.  But more importantly that it is wildly erratic, ranging from 0C to 12C at times.  An average of 100 measurements yields about 10C.  I just stuck it in a cup of coffee and the digital thermometer reads 61C and the 100-average of the pt100 reads 58C, so thats encouraging.  But individual readings range as low as 47C so its still erratic.

Here are the results:
[image: Tabulated Results]
[image: PT100 & Transmitter Herten]

Thanks

Comment: i think that the program that you show did not print that output .... please show the actual program that you used

Comment: The program I used is Arduino IDE.

Comment: Ive added the pictures of the pt100, the transmitter & its connections

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the transmitter wasn't programmed.  It needs to be programmed in order for the readings to work.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, your schematic is something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fV0aSZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The PT100 has a resistance of 100Ohm at 0°C and 138.5Ohm at 100°C.
The voltage at the AnalogIn is

$$V_{AI}=5V\cdot\frac{R_1}{R_1+R_{PT100}}$$

Since you have a 10Bit ADC and I quess it measures from 0V to 5V, you can also write:

$$n_{ADC}=1023\cdot\frac{R_1}{R_1+R_{PT100}}$$

That means, a higher temperature / higher \$R_{PT100}\$ leads to a lower voltage / lower ADC value. Just, what you observe.

In principle, you can alter the map function of your code: Calculate the ADC values e.g. for 0°C and 100°C, and map those to the temperature range. Get  the PT100 values from a table.
BUT: While \$R_{PT100}\$ is proportional to temperature (it's not, but for most applications one can assume it is), the formula above is not. That means, simply mapping ADC value range to temperature range does not give precise results. Depending on the needed temperature range, the precision may still be sufficient. For example, I proposed 0°C and 100°C.

If you need more precision, you can calculate the reverse of the formula above, to correctly calculate the resistance of the PT100 from the ADC value:

$$R_{PT100}=1023\cdot\frac{R_1}{n_{ADC}}-R_1$$

Further more: The resolution is not so good. A PT100 is very precise, but the change in resistance is just 0.3Ohm/°C. You need to be able to measure such small changes. Just calculate the difference in ADC value for 100Ohm and 100.3Ohm to check how much the ADC value changes per °C. Personally, I would recommend an NTC. Not so precise, but higher change in resistance, so better resolution.

Comment: ok so using this reference (https://www.regincontrols.com/Root/Documentations/89_43973/resistance_table_PT1000_sensors_prsh_en.pdf) I have tabulated the resistance for every 10 C deg increment.  And I came up with an nADC value of i.e., 680.28 for 50C, is that correct?

Comment: It cant be correct because for 25C (between 20 and 30C) the R value would have to be 695-703 and at room temp I get an analog value of 293-300

Comment: Correct. Now, since you added this screenshot of the code, it seems the schematic is different from what I assumed. I read something about 4-20mA, which results in 1-5V at the analog in, when driven through a 250Ohm resistor. So, I would ask what the actual schematic is. That's not clear from your drawing, and it seems to me neither mine nor something giving 4-20mA.

Comment: I just added the wiring setup

Comment: A PT100 is NOT linear... its a cubic

Comment: @JonRB: True. But in most cases, one can assume it. Nevertheless, I inserted this.

Comment: @sweber It comes back to accuracy... I usually treat it as linear over a 10deg range and I need +-2C.  -55C -> +150 there is a rediculous spread but +-10C might be ok

Answer (score 0):

You have a PT100 element *with a temperature transmitter on it*. 
That gives out a 4-20mA signal that is related to the temperature. You need to know the zero and span temperatures from the transmitter, and then you can correlate.

<s>According to the code in your screenshot, -50degC is 4mA and 20mA is +150degC.</s>

The measurment resistor is 237 ohm, so you know that -50degC is 948mV and 150degC is 4.74V.

Given 10 bit ADC and 5V ADC reference, 948mV is 1024*0.948V/5V = 194 ADC and 4.74V is 1024*4.74V/5V = 971 ADC.

---

Update according to the info in comment section:

Now that we know that the zero and span values the transmitter are:

```
 4mA  = -200 deg C 
20mA  =  600 deg C
```

the numbers in the calculations change slightly.

The measurment resistor is 237 ohm, so you know that -200 degC is 948mV and 600 degC is 4.74V.

Now, seeing as you in fact have not connected this to a standard Arduino, but this industrialized Arduino variant, you will have to adjust the ADC calculations for whatever is considered full scale on the industrialized device - PLC Analog IO is very often 0-10V. This has also been confirmed with the [industrial shields Arduino PLC *user manual*](https://www.industrialshields.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/ABOX-103-001-71.pdf) (see image below)

Given 10 bit ADC and 10V ADC reference,

\$-200\, C\, =\, 948 \,mV\Rightarrow \frac{0.948\, V\,  \cdot\,  1024}{10\, V} = 97\, ADC\$

\$600\, C\, =\, 4.74\,V\Rightarrow \frac{4.74\, V \, \cdot\,  1024}{10\, V} = 485\, ADC\$

[image]

Comment: Where do you get the -50 to 150 deg?  Was that from the old code I had?  I got that off the internet.  How do I know what temp range my transmitter is actually for?  All I know is that its a Herten branded transmitter

Comment: According to the invoice it says -200 to 600C but that gives -95 for room temp and the raw ADC value is 300.  Could the invoice data range be incorrect?  What do I do in this case because the supplier is completely unresponsive.

Comment: You need to know the zero and span temperatures. I have no clue what they are for your transmitter, -200degC to 600degC might be it, but i suspect that is the limits for the Pt element and thermowell. What is the model number for the transmitter? Did you buy it yourself? Then we might find the default measuring range.

Comment: Yes at the company they bought it both together.  The transmitter is a herten and the pt100 doesnt have a brand.  Ill post individual pictures of them.

Comment: I just got confirmation that my pt100 range is from -200 to 600C.  So I changed the code accordingly but get -95C.  Updated the OP

Comment: That's probably the temperature range of the temperature sensor. Like I said, if you post the make and model number of the temperature transmitter, then we might find the default range :)

Comment: The picture of the transmitter is in the OP.  I posted a top view and a side view which has a white-orangish label on it.

Comment: The other label on the transmitter reads Herten, the manufacturer, but no model.  The place I bought it hasnt responded :(

Comment: OK I think the transmitter has to be programmed for a temp range with an Rfid board.  Does anyone know how else to program it?

Comment: There is a mention about smartphone in the datasheet, but it's not a very informative datasheet (quite bad translation), and I couldn't find any apps on Google play. Also I couldn't access the manufacturers webpage, it's written in flash. I would contact them and ask how to get the info

Comment: Ok I got the data from the transmitter, its PT100, range from -200 to 600C and its 21mA max & 4 wire.

Comment: See my updated answer

Comment: Thanks, I changed the code and now Im getting anywhere from 200C to 400C to 600C for room temp.  The changes are due to how I wire the sensor to the transmitter.  Ive updated my OP to reflect the scenarios Ive tried.

Comment: Could you please help me with the wiring?  I've noticed differences in the wiring that I honestly didnt expect and Id like to rule those out of the equation.

Comment: I contacted IS but they use a 500Ω... they sent me this pdf: http://blog.industrialshields.com/es/how-to-connect-a-4-20ma-to-0-10vdc-analog-inputs/

Answer (score 0):

The transmitter appears to be loop-powered type so with 6V minimum supply you would need a power source of around 12V for 5V out and more like 24V for 10V out.

The absolute minimum voltage is 6V+ 0.021A*R, where R is the load resistor plus the round-trip resistance of the wires to the transmitter 4-20mA, but you really should have a couple volts (at least) more to allow for noise immunity, temperature coefficient of wires, connection resistance etc.

That's because in a two-wire system the supply voltage is the remaining voltage after the output voltage has been subtracted. You should allow for a bit of over range to distinguish between full-scale and open sensor.